# Receive push notification from server when app is closed

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp

I need advice after looking a lot about receive push/toast notifications regardless of the status of the application (closed or open).

The application communicates with a NodeJS API.

The idea is that a user logs in once to the application and then can receive notifications (depending on his account): i the user restarts his system for example, at startup he receives notifications without having to open the application (like the Mail application for example).

Most tutorials on MSDN use Azure and I don' use this. I would like to know if you have tips or links (tutorials, ...) for doing this in an UWP (or WinRT) application.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send push notifications from your NodeJS api via Windows Notification Service. This service has nothing to do with azure but when using Azure Notifications Hub it will be easier to get it implemented, but again this is not required;

In essence: 
- register your app in dev center
- obtain a client id and client secret to use WNS in the dev center
- When your app launch it obtains a push notification channel uri and sends this to your backend. Your backend need to save all the URI's for the different devices
- When you have a notification select the uri's of the devices you want to send the push notification to
- post a xml message (based on what you want to update, tile, toast, badge or raw) to the URI's. To be able to post you need to authenticatie with the client id and client secret

more detailed read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview#

Comment: Thanks, i will seek with your advices.